# Правильно ли сказать: человек недалёкий, но с амбициями?

Tags: значение-слов

Человек недалёкий, но с амбициями- допустимо ли такое выражение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тоже не вижу, к чему тут можно придраться.  А в чем Ваши сомнения?

Если по поводу орфографии, то все правильно (оформления вопроса я не касаюсь). 
"Не" здесь вполне логично написано. Хотя в принципе возможно обосновать и раздельное написание, но с очень "экзотическим" смыслом.

Comment: Да я и сама так считаю, просто возник спор, что значение слова "амбициозный" в настоящее время - это целеустремлённый, деловой, что не вяжется со словом недалёкий.(Это не моё мнение)

Comment: Так у Вас же противопоставление. Естественно, что "не вяжется".
Нет, амбициозный именно так и надо понимать, старое значение "амбициозный" сейчас уже мало кто помнит, но возражение при этом совершенно не по делу. Вот со старым значением (самолюбивый, неуравновешенный, излишне эмоциональный и проч.) фраза выглядела бы несколько эксцентричной, но тоже отнюдь не "запрещенной".

Answer (score 7):

По-моему,словосочетание вполне приемлемое. "Недалёкий", здесь - не очень умный, ограниченный, что не мешает такому человеку иметь амбиции (претензии, притязания на что-либо).

Comment: Ну да. Он с видами на ум.

Answer (score 0):

Но лучше по-русски: Человек недалёкий, но с гонором (но тщеславный, но с выпендрёжем).